# Entity in different package creates "references an unknown entity" (Multiple datasource scenario)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have currently 2 different datasource configurations that was working properly. But because the entities are getting more I want to put them on different packages.

Here is the folder structure and the DB configurations.

LocalDatabase configuration. (2 Pictures)

[image]

[image]

Folder structure is like this

[image: Folder structure is like this]

Exception that happens:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'localEntityManager' defined in class path resource [com/bennusoft/merlin/robot/business/database/LocalDBConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.bennusoft.merlin.robot.business.database.a.BilyonerBahisSoccerSpecialDatabase.iddaaGeneralDatabases references an unknown entity: com.bennusoft.merlin.robot.business.database.IddaaGeneralDatabase

If BilyonerBahisSoccerSpecialDatabase is at the same package there is no problem it will simply run. But when it is below package then that exception happens.

Somehow it is not seeing from the BilyonerBahisSoccerSpecialDatabase  to upper package in my point of view. But I do not know where I can actually.

How can I make this work with different packages?

**UPDATE 1:**
If I only keep in the factorybean with only .packages(IddaaGeneralDatabase.class) the problem is solved.

So my question actually changing. Why adding the different package breaks it?

Comment: Please also post the code for `BilyonerBahisSoccerSpecialDatabase` and `IddaaGeneralDatabase`.

Comment: @samabcde I updated the text. Do you still need the database code sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source code of [EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java) `Builder.packages(Class<?>... basePackageClass)` method

```
    public Builder packages(Class<?>... basePackageClasses) {
        Set<String> packages = new HashSet<>();
        for (Class<?> type : basePackageClasses) {
            packages.add(ClassUtils.getPackageName(type));
        }
        this.packagesToScan = StringUtils.toStringArray(packages);
        return this;
    }
```

And how you call the builder method

```
  return builder.dataSource(mysqlDataSource())
                .properties(hibernateProperties())
                .packages(IddaaGeneralDatabase.class)
                .packages(BilyonerBahisSoccerSpecialDatabase.class)
                .....
```

How you are calling packages method is not correct. Each time you call the `packages` method, `this.packagesToScan` of the `Builder` will be overridden. Hence after your second call, the `this.packagesToScan` is now `com.bennusoft.merlin.robot.business.database.a` and hence classes in package `com.bennusoft.merlin.robot.business.database` are not scanned. 
In addition, after your update, second call is removed, `this.packagesToScan` is keep as `com.bennusoft.merlin.robot.business.database`, this package and the sub-packages are scanned and hence the problem is solved.

If you need to add other classes which one package of the class is not the sub-package of other class, you can call `builder.packages(ClassA.class, ClassB.class)` instead.

Finally, next time please try to copy and paste the code to the post instead of screen cap, which help us to read/copy the code and understand your problem.

Comment: I will try. I think you are right so i mark as answer